# Python - Why are the words not randomly generating after each round in my Word jumble game?

Tags: python

Every time I complete a round, the next round 'jumble word' is exactly the same and is not randomly changing. Not sure what I've done wrong. I want it so that after you complete the word, you move onto the next round, and obviously it will be a different word. if any experienced programmers out there would like to help me out, please do.
Thanks in advance

```
# word jumble game

# the computer picks a random word and then "jumbles it

# the player has to guess the original word

import random

# create a sequence of words to choose from
WORDS = ("other", "jungle", "monday", "sword", "cat", "cheese", "snow", "england",
         "planet", "bread")

# pick one word randomly from the sequence
word = random.choice(WORDS)

# create a variable to use later to see if the guess is correct
correct = word
rounds = 10

# create a jumbled version of the word
jumble = ""

while word:
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
    jumble += word[position]
    word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]


print(  
"""
                    Welcome to Word Jumble!

             Unscramble the letters to make a word.
          (Press the enter key at the prompt to quit.)

               Score the highest points to win
                     There are 10 rounds
        Press '?' for a hint, but using a hint will deduct
                25 points of your total score

                         Good Luck!!!

""")
print ("The jumble:", jumble)
score = 100

# start the game

guess = ""
first = range(len(jumble))

rounds = 1
while True:

    guess = input("Guess or '?': ").lower()
    if guess == correct:
        score += 50
        rounds += 1
        print ("That's it! You guessed it!\n your score is", score)
        print("Round", rounds,"...")  
        print("The jumble is:", jumble)

    elif guess == '?':
        i = random.choice(first)
        print ( correct[i], "is the", i+ 1, "letter.")
        score -= 20

    else:
        print ("Sorry, thats not it. Try again.")
    if rounds == 10:
        print("That is the end of the game, your total score is", score, "Thank you for playing")
        break







input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: You should introduce functions to better organize your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are things I did to get your code to work:

- use `raw_input` instead of `input`
- split the code into playing a game of 10 rounds and a function that plays a single round
- have `play_round` return the score when the user guesses the word
- have `play_game` loop 10 times, calling `play_round` each time and creating a new word for each round
- create a function that jumbles a word
- create a function that selects a word from a list
- the main part of the program prints the header and calls `play_game`

Here's what `play_game` looks like:

```
def play_game():
    score = 100
    rounds = 10
    for round in range(rounds):
        word = select_word()
        jumble = jumbled(word)
        score = play_round(word, jumble, round + 1, score)
    print("That is the end of the game, your total score is {0}".format(score))
    print("Thank you for playing")
    raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are choosing the random selection outside of the while loop. Move that part of your code to the beginning of the while loop and it should choose a new selection every time the game starts over.

```
while word:
    word = random.choice(WORDS)
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
    jumble += word[position]
    word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]
```

You are going to need to change the condition of the while loop since word won't exist yet when it checks for it. Something like `while playing` and have `playing` be a bool that you can set to false so you can end the loop for whatever reason.

Comment: Sorry very new here, what while loop would i put it in as i have two?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually generate a new `jumble`. When the player wins, the following happens:

```
if guess == correct:
    score += 50
    rounds += 1 
    print ("That's it! You guessed it!\n your score is", score)
    print("Round", rounds,"...")  
    print("The jumble is:", jumble) # still the same jumble
```

You could encapsulate your jumbling into a function `jumbled_word()`, then

```
    jumble = jumbled_word()
    print("The jumble is:", jumble) # now a new jumble
```

Alternatively, try a structure like this (pseudo):

```
set up word_list
score = 0
while word_list:
    remove a random word from word_list
    jumble the word
    while True:
        guess
        if guess == word:
            score += 1
            break
print score
```

Comment: I haven't go onto functions yet as im following a book, so thats all a bit confusing to me.

Comment: OK, I have added a note on how you should roughly structure your code